# Tag synonym request [armed assault] → [arma]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [arma](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arma) and [armed-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armed-assault) should be synonyms.

Both tags refer to the same game: [ARMA: Armed Assault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARMA:_Armed_Assault).

From Wikipedia:

> ARMA: Armed Assault (stylized as ARMA; known as ARMA: Combat
>   Operations in North America), is a tactical military first- and
>   third-person shooter, released in late 2006.

[armed-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armed-assault) has only one question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged both [arma](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arma) and [armed-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armed-assault) tags into [arma-armed-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arma-armed-assault).

This seemed more appropriate given the full name of the game is [ARMA: Armed Assault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARMA:_Armed_Assault).